# Does AnimationDrawable keep running in background?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a custom view in Android which has uses an AnimationDrawable. If I have called AnimationDrawable.start() in my view, and I push the app to background without calling stop(), **is it draining system resources in the background ?**

If yes, how should I detect the "view" coming to foreground/background ? I am trying to avoid splitting the code into activity, because I want the custom view to be self-sufficient in handling it's own lifecycle.

EDIT: Please note that I understand that Activity.onPause and onResume calls can help me, but I don't want the consumers of my custom view to code for lifecycle methods - I want my custom view to take care of itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the view handle this on its own, override `onDetachedFromWindow()` and stop the animation within that. You can check for if it is animating within the `onDraw` and start again if it has been stopped.

Comment: Can you please answer the first part of the query - does the animation "run" while the app is in background ? I am assuming Android system will discard it as it's not on the main thread. But I don't know how to test.

Comment: Looking through the source, it appears it is using a handler to post future runnables. Based on that, I would say it indeed will continue running without a `setVisibile` or `stop` call.

Comment: This is not a safe place to stop animation. In case you switch between apps or simply tap on the Android Home button `onDetachedFromWindow()` won't be called

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, you can detect when the activity comes into the foreground/background by overriding its `onPause()` and `onResume()`, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    AnimationDrawable.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    AnimationDrawable.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the Activity (or Fragment) at some point if you want to manage the "App going to background" state.

I'd add two methods to the custom view:

```
public void startAnimation(){
 //start the AnimationDrawable
}

public void stopAnimation(){
 //stop the AnimationDrawable
}
```

Then, inside your Activity/Fragment

```
MyCustomView mCustomView

//initialize view


@Override
protected void onResume() {
  mCustomView.startAnimation();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  mCustomView.stopAnimation();
}
```

Comment: He already knew this, I guess. That's why, specifically noted following: "I want the custom view to be self-sufficient in handling it's own lifecycle"